# Show $u: K \to A$ is the intersection of the family $\{u_i\}_{i \in I}$ iff $u = \ker(p)$

Tags: category-theory

Let $u_i: A_i \to A$ such that $u_i = \ker(p_i)$, where $p_i: A \to B_i$. Let $p: A \to \Pi_{i \in I} B_i$, the induced morphism by the $p_i$. Show $u: K \to A$ is the intersection of the family $\{u_i\}_{i \in I}$ iff $u = \ker(p)$.

I'm stuck in both proofs. The exercise is full of definitions, so let me know if it's missing one to make the context clear.

First, suppose $u: K \to A$ is the intersection of the family $\{u_i\}_{i \in I}$. Thus, it exist $v_i: K \to A_i$ such that $u = u_i \circ v_i$. Since $p: A \to \Pi_{i \in I} B_i$ is the induced morphism by the $\{p_i\}$ family, $\pi_i \circ p = p_i$, where $\pi_i: \Pi_{i \in I} B_i \to B_i$ is the projection.

We want first to verify that $p \circ u = 0$. But we can only see that

$$\pi_i \circ p \circ u = p_i \circ u_i \circ v_i = 0 \circ v_i = 0$$

since $u_i = \ker(p_i)$. But I find no way to show that $p \circ u = 0$.

Am I missunderstanding something?

Comment: A morphism into a product is determined by its projections. You are done.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg God! Thanks for the appreciation.